I am getting "Parsing errors in Document (see Blender Console)" when importing a dae file
So, I am trying to import a dae file to blender but only get "Parsing errors in Document (see Blender Console)". When I got to the console I get no further error output about the exact reason. Any ideas how to fix this?
